# problem with the fread on TCP server client

Tags: c, sockets, server, tcp, fread

I'm building a app TCP server client, i want to send binary to the server/client (so i don't want to use send and recv) and i have a problem, i want to read the file descriptor of my client it's doesn't working i don't understand why because the server accept the client correctly so i have make this function:

```c
bool accept_and_read_client(){
    struct sockaddr_in new_client = { 0 };
    socklen_t length = sizeof(new_client);
    int val_return = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&new_client, &length);
    if(val_return < 0){
        syserr("error of accept");
        return true;
    }
    printf("accept of client successful\n");
    client_array[0].fd = val_return;
    
    size_t nbread;
    client_array[0].file = fdopen(client_array[0].fd, "w+");
    nbread = fread(&val_return, sizeof(char), sizeof(MAX_BUFF), client_array[0].file);
    if(nbread < -1){
        syserr("fread");
        return true;
    }
    printf("number i read : %ld\n", nbread); 
    return false;
}
```

when i start the server, the server wait client and when i make ./client test the server said:

```
accept of client successful
fread: Success
```

so the function fread fails.

on the client.c i do a fwrite like this:

```c
...
FILE* fdc = fdopen(sock_fd, "w+");

    if(fdc == NULL){
        syserr("error of fdopen");
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    
    size_t nb_write = fwrite(argv[1], sizeof(*argv), strlen(argv[1]), fdc);
    
    printf("number i write: %ld\n", nb_write);
    
    if(fflush(fdc)){
        syserr("fflush");
    }
```

if you want to see the client structure:

```c
struct client{
    int fd;
    // char buffer[MAX_BUFF]; 
    FILE* file;
};

struct client client_array[MAX_CLIENTS];
```

if somebody have a idea why fread don't work tell me please

Comment: First of all you attempt to read `sizeof(MAX_BUFF)` elements. That will most likely by `4` since I guess `MAX_BUFF` is a macro that expands to an `int` value, and on most systems `sizeof(int)` is equal to `4`. I suspect you want to read `MAX_BUFF` elements instead.

Comment: The second problem comes when you attempt to read `MAX_BUFF` characters into the `val_return` variable, since it's a single `int` variable that can only hold `4` bytes. What are you really trying to read?

Comment: Lastly, if `fread` fails you need to check `feof` and `ferror` to determine the cause of the failure. Also, it seems wrong to return `true` of failure and `false` when everything worked.

Comment: Oh and by the way, `client_array[0].fd`? Why do you use index `0` always? Will you not have more than one active connection at a time?

Comment: so according to you i read the bad thing, so i'm going explain you what i want to read, i send with the client a message on `argv[1]` so ./client test send the word "test" with the function `fwrite` and with the function on the server.c i want to accept client and read the fdc

Comment: for the test i just want to see the reading of one client on my array (so i check just the index `0` of my array), when that will work with one client i will make more connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fread` function probably *doesn't* fail, instead it's your check that is flawed:

```
size_t nbread;
...
if(nbread < -1)
```

The type `size_t` is *unsigned* so when you compare `nbread` with `-1` the value `-1` will be converted to an unsigned value as well. And that unsigned value will be *very large*, so `nbread` will always be smaller than `-1`.

The [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) function will not [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread#Return_value) `-1` or `EOF` on error, instead it will return a value smaller than the count argument (the third argument). That's the condition you need to check (`nbread < sizeof(MAX_BUFF)` with the possibly wrong code you currently show).

Comment: aaah i understand, when i comment the `if` that work but the output make me `number i read : 4` even i make `./clent hello_test` so you are right with the fact that i read `sizeof(int)`